# Creating a absolute input text relative to div parent

Tags: css, html

**all i want is to create a design that works on all browser**

only safari, opera work, other didn't,

here is my css;

```
div.parent{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}

div.parent label{
  display:inline-block
  vertical-align:top;
}

div.parent input[type="text"]{
  display:inline-block
  vertical-align:top;
  position:absolute;
  left:75px;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:initial;
}
```

here is my html

```
<div class="parent">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name here" />
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to be the same on all browsers?

Comment: what's the issue? This is fine, you dont have to use `position:absolute` either

Comment: sir i want my input text occupied some space on the div,

Comment: Also, if you didn't know there is Browser testing site: http://www.browserstack.com/ you can test your work there as well.

Comment: what do you really want!?

Comment: sir i used bootstrap to add some design on that, it really works fine in opera and safari, but when i tried to ie, chrome and mozilla, input text doesn't same the output in the opera.

Comment: What is `width:initial;`

Comment: occuppied some space on div sir, from the space not used by the other tags

Comment: It has to do with setting *left* and *right* properties to stretch the input.

Comment: yes sir. but how this not happen on the other browser? thank you sir

Comment: Please create a fiddle..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3pSRS/15/  here is my sample, in safari and opera it really work

Comment: The fiddle, like the example here, has a missing semicolon after `display:inline-block`. Twice. Fix that first. That said, I don't see much difference between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want ?

```
width:100%;
```

Instead of  ?

```
width : initial;
```